# SFML Window closes by itself when mouse goes outside of window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

My SFML application builds and runs as expected, but when let the mouse exit/enter the window on the left window-border, then it closes unexpectedly.

How can I make this error stop happening? I don't want the window to close unless I call it in the code.

Visual Studio 2019

SFML-2.5.1
(I think I downloaded the version: Visual C++ 15 (2017) - 32-bit)

Here's a bare minimum example of the code I'm running, that produces said error:

```
#include "SFML-2.5.1/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

sf::Vector2f window_size(800, 600);
sf::VideoMode video_mode(window_size.x, window_size.y);
sf::RenderWindow window(video_mode, "Hello");

int main() {
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        //Deal with input and update program
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed
            || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        //Draw things on screen
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        //Draw things here, not nothing right now    
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot examine `event.key` if `event.type` is not a keyboard event (e.g.  `sf::Event::KeyPressed`). [See](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Event.php#details).

Comment: Seems to have worked. Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as answered. So it's likely that it fired an event when I left/entered the window and it crashed because it couldn't read it?

Comment: @Einar `event` is a union of [several structures](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/Event_8hpp_source.php#l00221). That means that a lot of events is being generated and processed. To process the corrent one, you need to know the type of it, otherwise, you will get an UB

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Adding the title of the book that gave me this code for handling events / closing a window, just in case someone google's it: "C++ Game Development by Example" (Kindle location/page 1748).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sf::Event` is organised as a tagged union, where the `type` member is the tag, and the active member depends on the tag.

The `key` member is only active when `type` is one of the keyboard event types (`sf::Event::KeyPressed` or `sf::Event::KeyReleased`).

Examining an inactive union member is undefined behaviour. In practice, what's happening is probably something like the following. Some other event occurs, with a member which is numerically equal to `sf::Keyboard::Escape` and which physically shares the space with `key.code`. The program is accessing that member and erroneously interpreting it as `key.code`.

---

Relevant documentation:

- [Explanation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Event.php#details)
- [Code](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/Event_8hpp_source.php#l00221)